# Show lightning component to create new record in lightning experience

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Is it possible to override the standard create record page for a custom object with a lightning component, just like we do it with visualforce page in classic? 
I have googled this question a lot and here is what I found.

1. Create global actions. I can create a global action and assign the lightning component to it, but the problem is that the "New" button is always displayed on the Recent Items list view which opens the standard create page.
   Is there a way i can remove this button from the layout?
2. Create a visualforce page with lightning out. Looks like this is the only option unless there is some other way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Salesforce Lightning Roadmap](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/e-books/salesforce-lightning-roadmap.pdf), the ability to override standard actions with a Lightning Component is coming in Summer '17. (Take all forward-looking statements with a grain of salt.)

For the short term, I think you're stuck with the Lightning Out solution. You can't remove the New button from Recent Items unless you remove the ability to create new records period, which probably isn't what you want to do.